# Does haskell's foldr always take a two-parameter lambda?

Tags: haskell, fold

Haskell newb here

I'm working on this problem in haskell:

```
(**) Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements.
If a list contains repeated elements they should be replaced with a single copy of the element. The order of the elements should not be changed.

Example:
* (compress '(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e))
(A B C A D E)
```

The solution (which I had to look up) uses foldr:

```
compress' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
compress' xs = foldr (\x acc -> if x == (head acc) then acc else x:acc) [last xs] xs
```

This foldr, according to the solution, takes two parameters, x and acc.  It would seem like all foldr's take these parameters; is there any exception to this?  Like a foldr that takes 3 or more?  If not, is this convention redundant and can the formula be written with less code?

Comment: You can conceive of many instances where foldr takes more than 2 arguments, for example, `foldr (\f g x -> f (g x)) (\x -> x)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would use `foldr` to implement your `compress` function. What should happen if the argument is the empty list?

Comment: The ``foldr`` implementation would be fine you would just need to have a pattern first which can deal with the case of an empty list
``compress' [] = []``

Comment: @SimonGibbons, another approach that works with any `Foldable` and that plays well with list fusion is to use a `Maybe` for the accumulator.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`foldr` takes a function of 2 arguments, but this doesn't prevent it from taking a function of 3 arguments provided that function has the right type signature.

If we had a function

```
g :: x -> y -> z -> w
```

With

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Where we want to pass `g` to `foldr`, then `(a -> b -> b) ~ (x -> y -> z -> w)` (where `~` is type equality).  Since `->` is right associative, this means we can write `g`'s signature as

```
x -> y -> (z -> w)
```

and its meaning is the same.  Now we've produced a function of two parameters that returns a function of one parameter.  In order to unify this with the type `a -> b -> b`, we just need to line up the arguments:

```
a ->   |  x ->
b ->   |  y -> 
b      |  (z -> w)
```

This means that `b ~ z -> w`, so `y ~ b ~ z -> w` and `a ~ x` so `g`'s type really has to be

```
g :: x -> (z -> w) -> (z -> w)
```

implying

```
foldr g :: (z -> w) -> [x] -> (z -> w)
```

This is certainly not impossible, although more unlikely.  Our accumulator is a function instead, and to me this begs to be demonstrated with DiffLists:

```
type DiffList a = [a] -> [a]

append :: a -> DiffList a -> DiffList a
append x dl = \xs -> dl xs ++ [x]

reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' xs = foldr append (const []) xs $ []
```

Note that `foldr append (const []) xs` returns a function which we apply to `[]` to reverse a list.  In this case we've given an alias to functions of the type `[a] -> [a]` called `DiffList`, but it's really no different than having written

```
append :: a -> ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
```

which is a function of 3 arguments.

Answer (score 5):

As with all things in haskell have a look at the *types* of things to guide your way you can do this for any function in `ghci`.

Looking at this for foldr we see:

```
Prelude> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

This slightly abstract string can be written in english as:

`foldr` is a function that takes

1 ) a function with two parameters one of type `a` and one of type `b` and returns something of type `b`

2 ) A value of type `b`

3 ) A list of values of type `a`

And returns a value of type `b`

Where `a` and `b` are type variables (see [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) for a good tutorial on them) which can be filled in with any type you like.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that you can solve your `compress` problem using a `foldr` with a three-argument function.

```
compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress (z:zs) = z : foldr f (const []) zs z
  where f x k w | x==w      = k x
                | otherwise = x : k x
```

Let's dissect that. First, we can improve readability by changing the last two lines to

```
  where f x k = \w -> if x==w then k x else x : k x
```

This makes it evident that a ternary function is nothing but a binary function returning a unary function. The advantage of looking at it in this way is that `foldr` is best understood when passed a binary function. Indeed, we *are* passing a binary function, which just happens to return a function.

Let's focus on types now:

```
f :: a -> (a -> [a]) -> (a -> [a])
f    x    k
```

So, `x::a` is the element of the list we are folding on. Function `k` is the result of the fold on the list tail. The result of `f x k` is something having the same type as `k`.

```
\w -> if ....    :: (a -> [a])
```

The overall idea behind this anonymous function is as follows. The parameter `k` plays the same role as `acc` in the OP code, except it is a function expecting the *previous* element `w` in the list before producing the accumulated compressed list.

Concretely, we use now `k x` when we used `acc`, passing on the current element to the next step, since by that time `x` will become the previous element `w`. At the top-level, we pass `z` to the function which is returned by `foldr f (const [])`.

This `compress` variant is lazy, unlike the posted solution. In fact, the posted solution needs to scan the whole list before starting producing something: this is due to (`\x acc -> ...)` being strict in `acc`, and to the use of `last xs`. Instead, the above compress outputs list elements in a "streaming" fashion. Indeed, it works with infinite lists as well:

```
> take 10 $ compress [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

That being said, I think using a `foldr` here feels a bit weird: the code above is arguably less readable than the explicit recursion.

Comment: Thanks, this is helping me understand this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526740/why-is-the-f-version-of-this-program-6x-faster-than-the-haskell-one/37527523 . But by the way, changing the last two lines as you suggested to `where f x k = \w -> if x==w then k w else x : k w` doesn't seem to work. I get this: `*Main> compress [2,3,3] => [2,3,3]`

Comment: Could you please help me understand how the return value of `f x k w` is also a function - if you say that the accumulator is a function, doesn't that mean that it stays a function throughout the fold? If, in your example, `k` is a function that takes one argument, then `k x` and `x : k x` already include the argument, and since as I understand, the accumulator each time becomes the return value of `f`, doesn't it then become `k x` (or `x : k x`), which is just a list, rather than a function?

Comment: I wrote `k w` but I should have written `k x` -- edited.

Comment: `f x k` is a function, `f x k w` is a list. The first function `f x k` indeed takes `w` as argument, and returns a list. `k` is a similar function.

Comment: is `k x` a function? If the accumulator takes on that value, `k x`, how does the accumulator stay a function?

Comment: No, `k x` is a list. `k` is a function. The accumulator stays a function because it changes from `k` (a function) to `\w -> if ...` (another function, which is also `f x k`)

Comment: Btw, is it possible to adapt `foldM` to this 3-parameter technique?

Comment: @AleXoundOS I don't think so, since the result of `foldM` is in a monad, so returning `m (a->b)` won't let us pass the third argument. We could transform that into `a -> m b`, but in that case the monadic effect can not depend on `a`, so it's not completely general.

Comment: I could only satisfy compiler with `f :: (c -> IO [b]) -> a -> IO (c -> IO [b])` for `foldM` and make no use of it. In simple terms, I need that 2nd `c` to be accessible as an argument, but it's inside my output context. Wondered if it's still possible to avoid tuples for a temporary accumulator, so to speak. @chi, thank you for the explanation.