# Maximum Size Square of All 1's in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

if I have a matrix

```
m = 0 0 1 1 0
    0 1 1 1 0
    1 0 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1
    0 1 1 1 1
```

How do I find the the largest nXn sub matrix of m that is just 1's? 
This seems an OK problem in an imperative language, and indeed there are answers to this on Stack overflow using other languages, but I don't know where to start with Haskell.

we can assume that m is represented by

```
m = [ [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    , [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    , [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
    , [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    , [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ]
```

if that helps. In this case the answer would the bottom right 3x3 sub matrix.

Comment: What have you tried?  I'm a little surprised the imperative algorithms don't translate well enough in this case.  Also, consider using something besides lists, such as arrays or an actual matrix from hmatrix or some such.

Comment: One nice thing about haskell is that it's actually not that hard to implement imperative algorithms by opting into mutation with the State monad (or ST if you prefer), if it's too hard to figure out how to come up with a more functional algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *optimal* O(n^2) solution can be done using only lists and right folds <sup>(1)</sup>. I also generalize to maximum area sub-*rectangle*, not just squares. Limiting to only squares is an easy modification <sup>(2)</sup>.

```
import Control.Monad (ap)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

data Rect = Rect {
    row    :: Int, -- lower left row index
    col    :: Int, -- lower left column index
    width  :: Int,
    height :: Int
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Rect where  -- compare on area
    compare = comparing $ \a -> width a * height a
```

The idea is that first, at each cell, count *ones* upwards until you hit a zero. For the example in the question this would be:

```
[0,0,1,1,0]       [0,0,1,1,0]
[1,1,1,0,0]       [1,1,2,0,0]
[1,0,1,1,1]  >>>  [2,0,3,1,1]
[1,1,1,1,1]       [3,1,4,2,2]
[0,1,1,1,1]       [0,2,5,3,3]
```

and can be done by a right fold:

```
count :: Foldable t => t [Int] -> [[Int]]
count = ($ repeat 0) . foldr go (const [])
    where
    go x f = ap (:) f . zipWith inc x
    inc 0 = const 0
    inc _ = succ
```

Then, interpreting each number as height of a building, each row reduces to a *skyline* problem:

> Given height of buildings, find the largest rectangular banner which fits entirely under the skyline (i.e. outline of buildings).

For example, the skyline and the optimal rectangular banner in the last two rows would be as bellow (the banner is marked with #):

```
                            +
         +                  +
     +   +                  # # #
     +   # # #            + # # #
     + + # # #            + # # #
4th: 3 1 4 2 2     5th: 0 2 5 3 3
```

This problem can be solved in linear time for each row, by maintaining a stack (list) of buildings with increasing height. Whenever an item is popped out of the stack we update the current optimal solution:

```
solve :: Foldable t => t [Int] -> Rect
solve = maximum . zipWith run [0..] . count
    where
    run ri xs = maximum $ foldr go end xs 1 [(0, 0)]
        where
        end = go 0 $ \_ _ -> []
        go x f i ((_, y): r@((k, _):_))
            | x <= y = Rect ri k (i - k - 1) y: go x f i r
        go x f i y = f (i + 1) $ (i, x): y
```

then,

```
\> solve [[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1]]
Rect {row = 2, col = 2, width = 3, height = 1}

\> solve [[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
Rect {row = 3, col = 2, width = 3, height = 2}

\> solve [[0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,1,1,1]]
Rect {row = 4, col = 2, width = 3, height = 3}
```

---

<sub>1. this is optimal because it is linear in the number of elements of the matrix and you cannot do better than linear here.

2. in order to limit to just squares, you only need to change the lambda used in `compare` function to: `\a -> min (width a) (height a)`</sub>

Comment: "The idea is that, first for each cell find the longest continuous run of ones above that cell and starting at that cell" I am confused by this; in which direction are you counting in either case?

Comment: @matthias count ones upwards until you hit a zero; the shown example should help. For example look at the 2nd column

Comment: thanks. It clicked just before I saw your reply.  Thanks for your help. Now to spend the next hour trying to figure out your point free , partially applied folds :)

Comment: btw In trying to implement my own `aggr`, I did `foldl go (repeat 0) matrix` where `go xs ys =  zipWith inc xs ys` where `inc _ 0 = 0; inc x _ = succ x`. That was the way I was able to wrap my head around it. Can you please explain what the problem is with that, because you seem to have made efforts to use `foldr` and `ap`.

Comment: @matthias foldr _tends_ to perform better; but i think foldl would be fine here as well. `ap` is only to write a shorter code; it is equivelant to `go x f y = out: f out where out = zipWith inc x y`

Comment: Sorry, last question. how do the types match up between `go` and the `foldr`? I am confused as to what is actually part of the `go` evaluation in the `aggr xs =...` line.

Comment: @matthias see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27906660/625914 it is the same technique

Answer (score 3):

For examples of how to implement dynamic programming algorithms in Haskell, see this wiki page:

- [Dynamic Programming in Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Dynamic_programming_example)

Here is a simple example which solves the "Minimum Steps to One" problem described [here](https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-dynamic-programming). At an integer *n* you can move to *n-1* or *n/2* (if *n* is even) or *n/3* if *n* is divisible by 3. Here is a solution using Haskell arrays:

```
import Data.Array

stepsToOne n = arr
  where arr = array (1,n) [
                 (i,e)
                   | i <- [1..n]
                   , let e  | i <= 1    = 0
                            | otherwise = 1 + minimum (sub1 ++ div2 ++ div3)
                              where sub1 = [ arr ! (i-1) ]
                                    div2 = if mod i 2 == 0 then [ arr ! (div i 2) ] else []
                                    div3 = if mod i 3 == 0 then [ arr ! (div i 3) ] else []
              ]
```

**Update**

Here is the same algorithm implemented using lists:

```
stepsToOne' n = arr
  where arr = [ e | i <- [0..n]
                  , let e | i <= 1 = 0
                            | otherwise = 1 + minimum (sub1 ++ div2 ++ div3)
                              where sub1 = [ arr !! (i-1) ]
                                    div2 = if mod i 2 == 0 then [ arr !! (div i 2) ] else []
                                    div3 = if mod i 3 == 0 then [ arr !! (div i 3) ] else []
              ]

test = stepsToOne' 10
```

Note how `arr !! i` references `arr !! (i-1)` and possibly `arr !! (div i 2)` and `arr !! (div i 3)`. Haskell will figure out the order in which to evaluate the list items based on how they are related.

This is the same as writing:

```
stepsToOne' n = [ s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, ... ]
  where s0 = 0
        s1 = 0
        s2 = 1 + minimum [s1, s1]
        s3 = 1 + minimum [s2, s1]
        s4 = 1 + minimum [s3, s2]
        s5 = 1 + minimum [s4]
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! The links to the tutorial along with your answer will prove helpful!